# angularjs - getting the element that is clicked

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation where I want to determine a bit about something that is clicked; Basically here is the layout.

```
<div ng-controller="DropDownController">
   <div class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="check($event)">
      <div class="container">
         <div>
            // lots of other content and layers
            <a href="#">This is somewhere in there</a>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

So then on the controller, it's very simple.

Basically, if the user clicks a hyperlink, it'll work as expected. But if they click anything else on the layer, it just ignores the click completely. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to determine if a link was clicked though.

```
app.controller("DropDownController", function($scope){
   $scope.check = function($event){
      // if the clicked target is an <a>, then proceed
   $event.preventDefault(); // should never reach this, if a link is clicked.
   $event.stopPropagation(); // should never reach this, if a link is clicked.
});
```

## Update

I've been able to detect the element using `$event.target.localName !== 'a'`, but this feels a bit hacky. I'm not sure what `localName` is, or how reliable it is. Is this a good surefire way to make sure it only reacts to an anchor? Or at the very least, something that I have demarcated as clickable?

Comment: If you want to check for a click on that link, why not place the ng-click directive on the anchor tag itself ?

Comment: Because I actually want to check for a click on anything _except_ the link.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle

Comment: What you can do is add a ng-click to the <a>, and if its clicked, then stop propagation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the $event.target.tagName property to find out if an anchor tag has been clicked, and this is standard. So you can be sure about this working in all scenarios.

```
if ($event.target.tagName === 'A') {
   alert('Link clicked');
}
else{
 //Do something else
}
```

I have created a JSFiddle for you. Should clear the concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/8KJ4Y/1/

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you very much for the help.